# What is the difference in meaning between: se celebra & celebra?

Tags: pronombres, reflexivos

I am having a hard time knowing when to use a reflexive pronoun before a verb.  I understand when they are used before reflexive verbs but I often see them in front of non reflexive verbs too.

For example, here is a paragraph from a story I had to read for my Spanish homework.

> La tradición de día de los muertos tiene su origen en una celebración indígena.  Se celebra principalmente en Mexico y Estados Unidos

Questions:

1. Why do you have to put "Se" in front of celebra- "Se celebra"?
2. How does this change the meaning compared to if you just wrote "celebra"?

Another example,
What is the difference in meaning between: Sí te puedes y sí puedes

Gracias

Comment: It is impossible to use a reflexive pronoun with a non-reflexive verb, as the simple act of using a reflexive pronoun makes the verb reflexive. Although in this case, it's not actually reflexive.

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1078/12

Comment: You know what I mean... 
Verbs that are traditionally listed with a se at the end of the infinitive.  
The verbs related to personal care or daily routines.

Comment: There are indeed many verbs which are commonly reflexive, but there's no magical "reflexive" property inherent in any verb. Even the commonly reflexive verbs can be done to other people "Yo bañé al bebé."

Comment: I see what you mean.  I get really confused if "se" is plural or singular

Comment: 'se' is both :)

Comment: And by the way, welcome to the site. It's a good question!  I hope you find the answers helpful.

Comment: I know it's both...hence why it's confusing to me when translating the meaning of the sentence from Spanish to English.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

1. It is necessary to show the correct use of '*celebra*' in a passive voice:

   - With *se*: *(se celebra = es celebrado/celebrada)* -> (it) is celebrated

> *Se celebra principalmente en Mexico y Estados Unidos.*
>
> It is celebrated mainly in Mexico and USA.

1. Without '*se*', '*celebra*' turns into active voice = (*he/she/it* celebrates)

A deeper explanation can be found [here](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables) *(Real Academia Española, in Spanish)*

Comment: Indeed the refexive *celebra* **has the effect** of a passive voice, but it is **not** a passive voice.

Comment: THIS ANSWER WAS VERY HELPFUL.

Answer (score 1):

`Se celebra` translates to `They celebrate`
which is how we, English speakers, would say it.

For instance, `Aquí se celebra Navidad en Pascua`

`Here, they celebrate Christmas on Easter`

Not `they` as in 3rd person plural, but rather, `they` as in the people here.

When we are giving instructions we tend to say things like

---

`You mix the milk in with the eggs`

`Se mezcla el leche con los huevos`

---

`You soak the bread in the mixture`

`Se moja el pan en la mezcla`

---

`You cook the bread`

`Se cocina el pan`

---

In my opinion, the best real world example to understand this passive `se` is this:

`¿Cómo se dice 'something' en español?`

It translates semantically as

`How do you say 'something' in Spanish?`

but literally as :

`How is 'something' said in Spanish?`

`Cómo dice...`

This translates to something indicative

`How does he/she/it say ... ?`

Where there is a pronounced subject in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, in this case **Se celebra** would be in passive voice, what is called *pasiva refleja*. You could use **celebra** or **celebran** if you have a subject:

> (Él) celebra su cumpleaños este viernes.

Could you put some example for the case **Sí te puedes** and **sí puedes**?. I would say you need a comma: **Sí, te puedes** + sentence, or **sí, puedes**. Otherwise it is probably not correct.

> Sí, te puedes ir a la hora que quieras.
>
> ¿Puedo coger uno? Sí, puedes.

Comment: Thank you.  I get confused with knowing if se is singular or plural because it's for both.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key: "celebra" cannot be alone. You need a subject who is doing the celebrating.

Rafael y Carolina celebran su aniversario de casados.

When there is no subject (indefinite, or too many, such as a whole country), you use "se".

"Este miercoles se celebra la Independencia de Venezuela"

Answer (score 0):

For this instance I often take the "**se**" to mean the royal "**one**" like in English.

**Se** celebra principalmente en Mexico y Estados Unidos

**One** celebrates mainly in Mexico and US.

It can then work for You plural, they or a single person.

If you left out the se/one it doesn't sound right "celebrates mainly in Mexico and the US" who does?