# Differences between "passive se" and "impersonal se"

Tags: gramática, voz-pasiva, oraciones-impersonales

There's [a similar question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/what-exactly-are-the-passive-se-and-impersonal-se), but the author and answers seem to focus more on using 'se' in reflexive verbs rather than the question mentioned in the title.

My understanding is that with both 'passive se' and 'impersonal se' we do not specify the subject who carries out the action.

About their differences, some sources ([here](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/spanish/phrases/passive-and-impersonal-se), [here](http://www.spanishgrammargenius.com/spanish_passive_se_impersonal_se.htm) and [here](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/87)) say that:

- **Passive se** is used with ***transitive verbs***; inferring ***people in general*** when talking about custom, rule, or general consensus; in the form of se + verb (3rd person ***singular or plural***), for example

  - *Aquí se habla español.*  (Spanish is spoken here.)
  - *Se vende la casa.*  (The house is for sale.)
- **Impersonal se** is used with ***intransitive verbs***; inferring an unknown subject when talking about ***specific actions***; in the form of se + verb (3rd person ***singular***)

  - *En el avión no se fuma.*  (People don't smoke on the plane.)
  - *Se come mucho en esta ciudad.*  (People eat a lot in this city.)

My question is, is the summary above correct?

Even among those sources the categorization of examples are different, for example:

> Aquí se habla español.

Is the 'se' here a 'passive se' or 'impersonal se'? In the explanation of [SpanishDict](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/87) it can be both (it doesn't enforce intransitive verb with 'impersonal se' though).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Impersonal "se"* and *passive "se"* work almost the same way, except for what you have already mentioned. So yes, your summary is perfectly correct. The difference between both is that the direct object of the active voice sentence becomes the subject in *passive "se"* sentences, while *impersonal "se"* sentences don't have a subject because, as you correctly assume, the active version contains an intransitive verb (and in Spanish, unlike English, only direct objects can be the subject of a passive sentence).

Consider:

> Aquí la gente habla español. Subject = la gente; verb = habla; direct object = español.
>
> Aquí se habla español. Subject = español; verb = (se) habla, where "se" is a reflex passive marker or "marca de pasiva refleja".

You can tell "español" is the subject because the verb "habla" must agree with it. If you change it with a plural Noun Phrase, you have to pluralize the verb too:

> Aquí se **hablan** varios idiomas. Subject = varios idiomas; verb = (se) hablan, where "se" is a reflex passive marker or "marca de pasiva refleja".

In *impersonal "se"* sentences, the verb can never be pluralized. Compare:

> En el avión la gente no fuma. Subject = la gente; verb = fuma; there is no direct object
>
> En el avión no se fuma. Subject = there's no subject; verb = (se) fuma, where "se" is an impersonal sentence marker or "marca de impersonal"

Since there's no direct object in the active sentence to start with, there's no subject in the passive one. You can easily tell one from the other by looking at the verb. If it is transitive and there's something that looks like an object, that's probably the subject, and you have to conjugate the verb accordingly (passive sentence). If the verb is intransitive, then it must always be in singular (impersonal sentence).

An exception to this rule is when the direct object is a person and is introduced by "a". From the [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables#sthash.1YO3fht9.dpuf):

> Si el elemento nominal expresa persona y no va precedido de la preposición a, se emplea también la construcción de pasiva refleja:
>
> Se buscan actores para la película.
> Se contratarán nuevos trabajadores para el proyecto.
> Se necesitan especialistas en informática.
>
> Si el elemento nominal expresa persona y va precedido de la preposición a, debe emplearse la construcción impersonal; por tanto, **el verbo irá en singular aunque el elemento nominal sea plural:**
>
> Entre los gitanos se respeta mucho a los ancianos.
> Se entrevistó a los candidatos para el puesto.
> Se busca a quienes presenciaron lo ocurrido.

In [SpanishDict](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/87), all the sentences below are said to be impersonal:

- Se habla español en Uruguay. (They speak Spanish in Uruguay.)
- ¿Cómo se va al teatro? (How does one get to the theater?)
- Se escribe “pastel” p-a-s-t-e-l. (You spell “pastel” p-a-s-t-e-l.)
- ¿Cómo se dice “table” en español? (How do you say “table” in Spanish?)
- Se dice que va a llover (They say it is going to rain.)

You can tell some of them aren't actually impersonal by changing the Noun Phrase. Consider

- Se **hablan** *varios idiomas* en Uruguay. (They speak several languages in Uruguay.)
- ¿Cómo se va al teatro? (How does one get to the theater?)
- Se escribe “pastel” p-a-s-t-e-l. (You spell “pastel” p-a-s-t-e-l.)
- ¿Cómo se **dicen** *estas palabras* en español? (How do you say these words in Spanish?)
- Se **dicen** *muchas cosas* (They say a lot of things.)

As you can see, the verbs in the first, fourth and fifth sentences changed so they would agree with the subject (the italicized parts), so they aren't actually impersonal but reflex passive sentences. The second one is impersonal because "ir" is intransitive, and the third one is tricky. I would call “pastel” p-a-s-t-e-l a *complemento circunstancial de modo*, or maybe a *complemento predicativo*, but not a subject. Had the same sentence been worded as *“Pastel” se escribe p-a-s-t-e-l*, then it would have been more evident that *Pastel* is the subject, and the sentence could have been classified as a reflex passive sentence as well.

What is curious about that page is that practically the same sentence ("Se habla español aquí" and "Se habla español en Uruguay") is classified first as an impersonal sentence and then as a passive one. Maybe it was just a slip. The rest of the information from the same page is correct.

For a more detailed explanation of the uses of "se", check out [this entry](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs) on the RAE (only in Spanish).

---

**Edit:** I just checked out the other two sources you mention. [Wyzant](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/spanish/phrases/passive-and-impersonal-se) got it right except for when they say "The pronoun *“lo”, “la”, “los”* or *“las”* may replace the direct object. Example: “Aquí se lo habla” (el Español)". That's utterly wrong. Under no circumstance can a passive sentence take a direct object; what they call direct object is actually the subject, and of course "aquí se lo habla" is nonsense. [SpanishGrammarGenius](http://www.spanishgrammargenius.com/spanish_passive_se_impersonal_se.htm) is both concise and correct.

A key concept here is that just because a verb can take a direct object it doesn't mean it's working transitively, so to speak. A good example is given in the first page:

- “En Colombia se baila mucho la Cumbia.” Since “la Cumbia” is a direct object of the verb “bailar”, this sentence is in the passive voice.
- “En Colombia se baila mucho.” Since there is no direct object for the verb “bailar”, the sentence is an impersonal one.

The fact you decide to call the first sentence impersonal or passive is unimportant: if the only difference is verb agreement, which only makes a difference when the subject is plural, and the subject is absent when the verb is working intransitively, whatever you decide to call it won't have any implications, neither grammatically nor pragmatically.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply, the links on RAE are also very helpful!

Comment: Explicas muy bien. Gracias.  Pero ahora tengo dudas de los usos de los dos. A qué circunstancias se los usa (se los usan?)

Comment: I do have one question similar to Cadenza's: you said _"Aquí se lo habla"_ is not correct. I'm wondering if it's the structure (I think people say "Este no se lo **hace**", we can use "lo", "la", "los" and "las" with "passive se", right? Like, "Los libros, no sé dónde se los **encontraron**", is it a correct sentence?), or because the term "direct object" is incorrect (should be "subject")?

Comment: "Los libros, no sé dónde se los encontraron" is a whole different sentence structure. It is correct, but it is neither passive nor impersonal; it's an ethic dative. See how you can omit it without changing the meaning of the sentence:  "Los libros, no sé dónde se los encontraron" = "Los libros, no sé dónde los encontraron" (The books, I don't know where they found them). To make it passive, you are right in that you can't use the pronoun "los" there: (+)

Comment: (+) "Los libros, no sé dónde se encontraron" is correct, although a more natural wording would be "No sé dónde se encontraron los libros", but that would be ambiguous because that "se" could be construed both as a passive marker (I don't know where the books where found) or an ethic dative, which would make the sentence active (I don't know where they found the books). The best choice here would be to use an "impersonal they" construction ("No sé dónde encontraron los libros"). Whether that last sentence is understood as personal or impersonal would depend on the context.

Comment: @Cadenza Your sentence is correct, but it is rare in Spanish. Contrary to the standard rules, you can use a transitive verb with a DO in an impersonal sentence and keep the DO as such instead of turning it into the subject.  Both "¿En qué curcunstancias se usan?" (passive sentence) and "¿En qué circunstancias se los usa?" (impersonal sentence with a DO) are technically correct, but the latter sounds pretty bad (and I advise against using it). To know when to use each, the three pages linked in the question – and the question itself – provide some good explanations.

Comment: @Yay.  Is it `1. En qué circunstancias se usan?`<--- passive sentence? `2.  En qué circunstancias se los usa?` <--- ethic dative? .......….....`"no sé dónde se encontraron los libros"`=  I don't know where the books can be found?? <---- one meaning??.......... `1. A qué circunstancias se los usa?`   `2. A qué circunstancias se los usan.`  (Cuándo usa "usa" y "usan"??

Comment: @cadenza ¿En qué circunstancias se usan? is a passive sentence and is okay. ¿En qué circunstancias se los usa? is an impersonal sentence (no ethic dative). The verb is plural (“usan”) if you’re using a passive construction. It is in singular (“usa”) if you use an impersonal construction. Since the DO should become the subject, the second option is best avoided. But you’re making several questions all at once and I don’t fully understand what you mean. If you’re stuck with a sentence you can ask a question and I’ll be glad to answer that, but the comments aren't the best place to address them.

Comment: @Yay Thanks again for the answers. Although I'm not 100% sure I understood how to use "lo", "la", "los" and "las" in some of the circumstances, I believe that's because I still need to learn more about the grammar. Your answers serve as a good reference for me. ¡Muchas gracias!