# Can the pronoun "se" refer to plural?

Tags: gramática, conjugación

Saw this sign outside a small convenience store in Argentina:

> se aceptan tarjetas de credito

While "aceptan" is obviously the third person plural conjugation of "aceptar", I thought the pronoun "se" refers to the impersonal third person singular. Do I miss something?

Comment: Note well, this is not an impersonal phrase, but the kind called *pasiva refleja*. It is equivalent to *«Tarjetas de crédito son aceptadas»* (only that's rather an unnatural way of saying it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Se* doesn't distinguish number; it works both as singular and plural. In this it's different from other pronouns that form their plural with *-s* (there's *los, las, les* but there's no **ses*). In this particular example *se* refers to the third person plural, agreeing with *aceptan* and *tarjetas de crédito*.

Since the second person pronouns *usted* and *ustedes* work grammatically as if they were third person, *se* can also refer to them.

Note well,

> *se aceptan tarjetas de crédito*

is **not** an impersonal phrase, but one of the kind called ***pasiva refleja*** ("reflexive passive"). It is equivalent to *«Tarjetas de crédito son aceptadas»*, only that would be rather an unnatural way of expressing the idea. There are a couple of questions addressing the [difference between impersonal and passive](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/differences-between-passive-se-and-impersonal-se), which is sometimes hard to spot.

Answer (score 3):

Se can refer to:

- 2nd person singular formal (usted)
- 2nd person plural formal (ustedes) [regions with vosotros]
- 2nd person plural informal (ustedes) [regions without vosotros]
- 3rd person singular (él, ella)
- 3rd person plural (ellos, ellas)