# Why is the indirect object pronoun "te" used in "¡lávate las manos!" and other such sentences?

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos

I first heard the phrase "¡lávate las manos!" in [a clip from American Dad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eacj334RVjc).

Why is the (indirect?) object pronoun *te* necessary here? Why wouldn't it be "¡lava las manos!".

My Colombian friend also said to me last night (if I'm quoting correctly) "Vamos a lavarnos los dientes". When I heard that sentence, I hear "We're going to brush us the teeth" even though it translates to "We're going to brush our teeth". The "nos" seems redundant but I couldn't get my friend to explain. It just seemed clear to him. But it's not yet clear to me.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25987/wie-sage-ich-i-brush-their-teeth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect (judging by the "*indirect?*"), this "lavar" is not intransitive but pronominal.

In the [DLE entry for "lavar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N18qWGb) you can read:

> 1. [tr.](http://no.link/) Limpiar algo con agua u otro líquido. [U. t. c. prnl.](http://no.link/)

Read about pronominal verbs in the DPD page "[Términos lingüísticos](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/terminos-linguisticos)":

> **13. verbo pronominal.** El que se construye en todas sus formas con un pronombre átono que concuerda con el sujeto y que no desempeña
>   ninguna función sintáctica oracional. Algunos verbos son
>   exclusivamente pronominales, como *arrepentirse* o *vanagloriarse*, y
>   otros adoptan determinados matices significativos o expresivos en la
>   construcción pronominal, como *caerse* o *morirse*, frente a *caer* o
>   *morir*.

But, [as you will see](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Verbos%20pronominales.htm), the subject is complex and verbs have been classified differently depending on the authors.

> El Diccionario de la lengua española de la RAE, a partir de la
>   decimonovena edición (1970), ya no califica el verbo *lavarse* ni
>   *alegrarse* como reflexivo, sino como pronominal. Y todos los verbos que
>   se pueden conjugar con los pronombres reflexivos (clíticos), tengan
>   sentido reflexivo puro o no, llevan la abreviatura: U. t. c. prnl. (=
>   usado también como pronominal).
>
> A pesar del cambio de nomenclatura de la RAE, algunos gramáticos, como
>   Marcos Marín (1980: § 13.8) siguieron clasificando los verbos como
>   *transitivos*, *intransitivos*, *reflexivos*, *reflexivos formales* o
>   *gramaticales* y *recíprocos*.

Go to "VERBOS TRANSITIVOS DE ACCIÓN REFLEXIVA" and you will read:

> El término ‘reflexivo’ se refiere solo a la identidad, en la realidad
>   designada, entre sujeto y objeto directo o indirecto de una oración:
>   *Luis se lava*. ***Luis se lava la cara***.
>
> El pronombre reflexivo indica que la acción expresada por el verbo
>   pasa, como complemento, al mismo sujeto que la realiza. Es decir, es
>   una palabra que repite el grupo del sujeto, en función de complemento.
>
> (...)
>
> Desde el punto de vista sintáctico, el pronombre reflexivo reproduce
>   como complemento directo o indirecto a la persona que funciona como
>   sujeto de un verbo usado como reflexivo.

And if you scroll down to "VARIACIONES GEOGRÁFICAS Y DIFERENCIAS DE REGISTRO" you will learn that

> En el español hablado en la zona noroccidental de España tienen
>   variantes no pronominales algunos verbos que no las poseen en otras
>   áreas:
>
> *romper* (*El jarrón rompió*)
>
> *marchar* (*Tengo mucha prisa, marcho enseguida*)
>
> *pudrir* (*Las manzanas pudrirán*)
>
> *lavar* (***Voy a lavar las manos***)
>
> *poner* (*Puso la chaqueta y marchó*)

So, though in English you use the possessive to point out whose the hands are of, and in Spanish we use the pronoun, this pronoun is not essential to the understanding.

Comment: Yes, this makes it clear as I did not know about pronomial verbs before.

Answer (score 2):

The object pronouns play a necessary role to show who or what we are referring to. If it's not placed, the meaning can change.

> Láva**te** las manos = las manos tuyas.
>   Lava las manos = ¿Cuáles? ¿Las tuyas o las mías?
>   Vamos a lavar**nos** los dientes = nuestros dientes.
>   Vamos a lavar los dientes = ¿Cuáles? ¿De quién?

The same happens when using *gustar*:

> Me gusta bañar**me** = A mí.
>   Me gusta bañar = ¿A quién o qué cosa?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the indirect object is a means to express the same thing the possessive expresses in English regarding the body parts; bare in mind that for Spanish-speaking people, possessives are redundant: for example in "my head aches", whose head could hurt, if not mine?

You could look at it as the way Spanish expresses mediopassive voice (compare to, e.g., Greek).